# How can I add folder icon to my listview

Tags: android, listview

```
for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    File file = files[i];
    path.add(file.getPath());
    if(file.isDirectory())
        item.add(file.getName() + R.drawable.folder); /* it doesn't work, because it shows numbers instead of folder icon */
    else
        item.add(file.getName());
}
```

It doesn't work; it shows numbers instead of the folder icon.

Comment: You're concatenating it... strings aren't magic.

Comment: Ok, but what is your suggestion?

Comment: Your on the right track, I posted some links to open source code so you can continue creating your own :)

Comment: need a little more context:  What kind of object is "item" ?

Comment: this is the sorce code what I used:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There several Android tutorials on make file mangers and lists: [Android Programming: Where To Start For Creating A Simple File Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108881/android-programming-where-to-start-for-creating-a-simple-file-browser)

That link - on StackOverFlow - has other links that good for what you are trying to work on. Also, you can use the source code from OpenIntents open source file manager:

OpenIntents: http://www.openintents.org/en/download

Source Code: 
http://code.google.com/p/openintents/downloads/detail?name=FileManager-source-1.0.0.zip&can=1&q=

To see what Open Intents File Manager looks like, you can check it out here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.filemanager

Let me know if this helps!