# Android attachment / file picker into InputStream string

Tags: android, inputstream, filepicker

I want to create a similar function as below image. Allow user to select image / pdf file from device and convert the file into inputstream as string and sent to server. 
 I had go through this [Attaching a file of any type in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399119/attaching-a-file-of-any-type-in-android-application) and successfully to call for document but does not have option for camera. Appreciate if there any source i can refer or library that able to perform this:

provide option to select from gallery/take new photo/document

Select file and convert to string (inputstream)

[image]

```
//Json that server going to receive
"Attachment": {
"InputStream": "string",
"FileName": "string"
}


/*My Code*/
public void goToAttachment(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*|application/pdf");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, null), SELECTFILE_RESULT_CODE);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    switch (requestCode){
        case SELECTFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                fileSrc = data.getData().getPath();

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to get first `Bitmap` of Image and then get `String` from `Bitmap` Object:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    switch (requestCode){
        case SELECTFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
          // Let's read picked image data - its URI
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
        String bmpString= bitMapToString(bitmap)
        cursor.close();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

You can use below method to convert `Bitmap` to `String`:

```
public String bitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
     byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
     String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
     return temp;
}
```

you can change `Bitmap` Compress format `JPG`  or `PNG` as par your image.

For PDF and other file you can use below method to convert it into String.

```
private String getString(String filepath) throws IOException {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return encoded;
        }
```

To get File path you can use bellow code:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try { 
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what about .pdf doc?