# How to open a file browser in Android?

Tags: android, file-browser

I am developing on a Android 4.0.3 device. How do I open a file browser for my app? Is there one built in the to Android SDK? Do I have to write my own?

I don't want my app to depend on a the user installing a separate app for file browsing.

Answer (score 22):

To get a file from a file browser, use this:

```
        Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        fileintent.setType("gagt/sdf");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(fileintent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "No activity can handle picking a file. Showing alternatives.");
        }
```

I'm not quite sure what the gagt/sdf is for... it seems to work in my app for any file.

Then add this method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Fix no activity available
        if (data == null)
            return;
        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                //FilePath is your file as a string
            }
        }
```

If the user doesn't have a file manager app installed or preinstalled by their OEM you're going to have to implement your own. You might as well give them a choice.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this one will help you for file picking:

```
public void performFileSearch() {

    // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
    // browser.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
    // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
    // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
    // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
    // it would be "*/*".
    intent.setType("image/*");

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

The code is from this documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html
Refer to it for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If someone would still need it for newer versions, it got updated with developing Storage Access Framework by Google for SDK >= 4.4. Check this Google site for further details:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no single file-management app that is installed across **all devices**.
You probably want your app to be also working on devices with Android 3.x or lower. 
The best choice you have though is writing your own file-manager. It isn't as much effort as it might sound, there is a lot of code on this already out there on the web.

Comment: maybe i need to work on my googling skills but i am having trouble finding an easy to follow code example...

Comment: http://madteam.co/news/2011/10/android-diy-making-a-file-manager/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108881/android-programming-where-to-start-for-creating-a-simple-file-browser should provide an entry point