# Android opening consecutive folders .. one from another

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I'm implementing a file  manager in which i'm opening a folder on a listView  which contains another folders and so on .... I'm wondering how could I implement opening these consecutive folders, do I have to write a series of activities which would be up to 10

Comment: refer [Android Programming: Where To Start For Creating A Simple File Browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108881/android-programming-where-to-start-for-creating-a-simple-file-browser)

Comment: you have to use fragment instead of activity.

Comment: thanks @RaviRupareliya , I've done most of the work in the file Browser I just still have two points to finish ..this is one of them

Comment: @vishalpatel thanks vishal... but with fragments will I have to write many of fragments .....one for each folder?

Comment: no.. you have to manage  your Adapter class .. for  directory file and file type

Comment: @vishalpatel would you provide me more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify: you are asking how you can implement a directory navigation GUI that expands a directory into a list when selected. And you are confused that if you navigate into multiple levels of nested directly you will need to write that that activities, one for each level.

Obviously you do not have to write one activity for each directory level you navigate into.

- You can use just one ListView inside one Activity, but repopulate the content of the ListView every time user opens a directory
- If you want a your ListView of directory content inside a sliding panel, take a look at ViewPager.

Comment: I used one activity and i populated the new floder content each time the user clicks on a folder item on the list ...... but how to return back to the previous list

Comment: I see, your are confused about how to keep a path of bread crumb. You have to realize that you can keep a data structure internally to keep track of the current path. Such as using a stack. When you go up one level, pop the stack; when you open a directory, push that directory onto the stack.

Comment: Even better, don't use a stack but use Java [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), it has everything you need to keep track of current path.

Comment: but how which method i use when i return back

Comment: path = path.subpath(0, path.getNameCount()-1);

Comment: i  mean returning from the current listView to the previous one within the same activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131512/discussion-between-satech-and-flintlock).